# How to search for a folder inside another specific folder in Spotlight

Tags: macos, search, finder, spotlight, desktop-search

Is possible to tell spotlight to search for a folder "x" that is contained within folder "y"?

For example, I have several dirs named "june" in my computer, but one of them is inside a dir named "pictures". This is the one I want to find by using a query such as `june dir:pictures`.

```
.
├── documents
│   └── june
├── downloads
│   └── june
├── june
├── pictures
│   └── june               //I need to find this specific june
├── presentations
│   └── june
└── statements
    └── june
```

I know it's possible to search in finder or use the find/grep commands for it, but that's out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any way to do that from the Spotlight menu, but you could always open the folder in Finder, start a search, and select the folder from the scope bar:

[image]

or use `mdfind`:

```
mdfind -onlyin ~/Pictures/ june
```

---

[kMDItemPath cannot be used with mdfind](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/MetadataAttributesRef/Reference/CommonAttrs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001694-SW1). Otherwise you might use something like `'kMDItemPath=="*pictures*/june/"`.

However mdfind combined with grep should be as fast as mdfind alone:

```
mdfind 'kMDItemFSName==june' | grep '/pictures/'
```

Comment: Of course. But that is another thing, assuming I know where to look for (in the example, Pictures). I want something broader than that, since I don't know where the file/folder is. Well, looks like is not possible out of the box.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the answer. Could you just grep the output of mdfind?

Comment: Sure, thanks. I can `grep` or `find` it. So the answer is: not possible trough spotlight.